# I can't install ubuntu with UNetbootin

Tags: boot, system-installation, error-handling

I cannot install ubuntu with UNetbootin and I don't have any spare pc, flash or anything like that
I am install on the hard disk and I only have 1 hard disk because I am on a older laptop, everything works well but after I select the UNetbootin (from the blue screen wher eyou have to select windows or UNetbootin) it loads a little bit and then it gives me an error of something like I missing file in the ISO, I've reinstalled the image and UNetbootin but it still says there's a missing file, what do I do? (I am on windows 10)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. 
Did you do a `checksum` of the `.iso`? If it doesn't match download the .iso again.
Try again with Unetbootin and see if it works. If not:
You can install `Grub2Win` on your `Windows`. Place the `.iso` in the **root** of the drive ( `C:\Ubuntu blah.iso` ). 
Then configure `Grub2Win` that it can also boot from the `.iso`. ( click `manage boot menu` [image: grub2win1],
 add iso [image: grub2win2]. Where it now says Ubuntu ( arrow ), change that to iso file and fill in the choices step by step )
Update the configuration file.
Set `Grub2Win` as default *bootloader*. Foto 1; in the green it will have a button that say `make Grub your default bootloader`
When booting up you should see a boot menu where you can choose between `Windows` and the `.iso`.[image: grub2win3]. ( The end result should be different in your case. )
When booting choose the `.iso`
Choose try `Ubuntu`.
Check if all your hardware works.
Install `Ubuntu`.
Hope this helps you out. I don't have experience with `UNetbootin`, but with `Grub2Win` I do. Hardcore Linux guys and girls hate this program but I love it, and it works perfectly for me. Hope it will for you too.

Comment: Thank you I will try it